# Get column names from Hive to CSV using Airflow hook using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, hive, hiveql, airflow

I am using Airflow hiveserver2 hook to get results from Hive table and load into CSV. The hook `to_csv` function has a parameter '`output_headers`'. If set to true, it gets column names in the form of `tablename.columnname` along with data and writes to a CSV file. In the CSV header I just need the column names and need to get rid of the tablename from `tablename.columnname`. Can I override the parameter somehow to just get column names? Is there any other way to just retrieve column names using `HiveServer2Hook`?

I have connected to Hive using HiveServer2Hook. I have also executed the hooks `to_csv` function. I just need to change the format of the column names returned using the function. Here is the link to the hook. You can find the `to_csv`, `get_records` and `get_results` function under `HiveServer2Hook`.

```
https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.html
```

I also tried running 'describe tablename' and 'show columns from tablename' for HQL but the hive hook's `get_records` and `get_results` function breaks on header issue as the result returned by 'describe' and 'show columns' is not in the expected format.

tried the following:

```
1) describe tablename;
2) show columns from tablename;
```

The airflow hook has functions `get_records` and `get_results`. Both break on following line when I use above HQL statements.

```
 header = next(results_iter)
```

Is there any other way to get column names, write to `CSV` and pull data using `HiveServer2Hook` and `Python`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and here is what I found as an easier way to do it.

Pass the below hive_conf parameter to `to_csv(..)` method

```
hive_conf={"hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names": "false"}
```

This will suppress the table name before column name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HiveMetastoreHook`'s [`get_table(..)` function](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L608) to get exact column names as follows

```
# imports
from airflow.hooks.hive_hooks import HiveMetastoreHook
from hmsclient.genthrift.hive_metastore import ttypes
from typing import List

# create hook
hive_metastore_hook: HiveMetastoreHook = HiveMetastoreHook(metastore_conn_id="my-hive-metastore-conn-id")

# fetch table object
table: ttypes.Table = mt_hook.get_table(table_name="my_table_name", db="my_db_name")
# determine column names
column_names: List[str] = [field_schema.name for field_schema in table.sd.cols]
```

..

After this you must subclass `Hiveserver2Hook` to modify the `to_csv(..)` method. In particular, changing the [`header` value](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L928) to the `column_names` extracted above should suffice.

---

Alternatively if you do not wish to subclass `Hiveserver2Hook`, you can just implement it's `to_csv(..)` separately (such as in a *`hive_utils.py` file*) and achieve the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Most queries that throw this error have their own function from the `HiveMetastoreHook` object that can provide the correct result. Most of these have to do with table and partition metadata.